# Bean validation on class level not working for generic classes

Tags: java, bean-validation, nested-generics

I have a custom annotation to use on a generic class. It looks like this:

```
@MyAnnotation
public class MyGenericClass<T extends AnInterface> implements MyTemplate<T>  {

  @NotNull
  private Operation op;

  private T value;

  ...
}
```

`@MyAnnotation` annotation validates `T` based on a value of the attribute `op`. Here the validator associated to it:

```
public class MyAnnotationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TheAnnotation, MyGenericClass<? extends AnInterface>> {

@Override
public void initialize(TheAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {}

@Override
public boolean isValid(MyGenericClass<? extends AnInterface> operation, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    if(operation == null) return true;

    AnInterface value = operation.getValue();

    if(value == null && "add".equals(operation.getOp().name())) return false;
    if(value == null && "replace".equals(operation.getOp().name())) return false;
    if(value == null) return true;

    if("add".equals(operation.getOp().name())) {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<AnInterface>> violations = validator.validate(value);

        return violations.isEmpty();
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

At runtime I have the classCastException `"exception":"java.lang.ClassCastException","message":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy226 cannot be cast to ...MyAnnotation`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. It was not related to generic types. I assigned the wrong annotation to the `ConstraintValidatorContext`. After changing  `TheAnnotation` by `MyAnnotation` everything was fine.